# Javascript WIndows PopUp function conflict

Tags: javascript, window

I have a problem for my JavaScript pop up window. I got two window pop up functions:

The first one window pop up will open a new window contains a page URL

Look like:

```
<a class="" onclick="kmt_contactFormPopup('http://uk.support.tomtom.com/app/ask',this)">[To the contact form..]</a>



function kmt_contactFormPopup(emailURL, aTag) 
 { 
     params = 'width=950px';
     params +=',height=700';
     params += 'screenX=250, screenY=80,';
     params +='scrollbars=yes';
     newwindow=window.open(emailURL,'name',params);

     if (newwindow.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
 }
```

The second window pop up will grab the content in this HTML page and show the content in pop up window.

For instance;

```
Collect the error log <a href="#BOX01" onclick="kmt_ShowBoxPopup('BOX01', this);"><strong>[Show me how..]</strong></a><br /><br />
 <div id="BOX01" style="display:none">
     <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="background-color:#ffffff;">
```

```
                      </tr>
     </table>
 </div>
```

The javascript

```
 function kmt_ShowBoxPopup(targetDivID, aTag)
     {
  var orgin_div_content=document.getElementById(targetDivID).innerHTML;

  showBoxPopupWin =window.open("",'name','height=400,width=710,screenX=250,screenY=80, scrollbars=yes');

  showBoxPopupWin.document.write (orgin_div_content);

  if (window.focus) {showBoxPopupWin.focus()}
 }
```

If I run the contactForm pop up function first, and then I click on the showBox function. I got an error message in JavaScript:

Permission denied for  to get property Window.document from 
Line 43

it is this line of code

```
  showBoxPopupWin.document.write (orgin_div_content);
```

I would like to have different pop up windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
showBoxPopupWin =window.open("",'name', ...
```

Won't open a new blank writable document in the window if the window called `'name'` is already open. It will keep the old document, which, being an external link, you can't write to.

You will have to open a window with a different name (usually `_blank`, to prevent any window name clashes).

(Also consider giving your local variables `var` to avoid accidental global clashes, and using proper links with `href` instead of JS-only faux-links.)